# systemverilog pointer to function

Tags: system-verilog

I am looking way to create same parameterized class where based on parameter methods for the class will behave differently. In C i would implement this by using pointer to function and during creation will assign this pointer to different function, so user call same API.

The only way i can find would be using class that extends from class which methods i can override, but this would require user create different class.

Can't find in SystemVerilog something like pointer to function:

```
void (*foo)(int);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in your thinking there are no pointers to functions in SystemVerilog and that you would have to wrap your functions in a class. This is known as the [Command Design Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258364/what-is-the-difference-between-a-functor-and-the-command-pattern#:%7E:text=A%20functor%20is%20an%20implementation,implement%20the%20%27Command%20Pattern%27.&text=%40Martin%20York%3A%20You%20might%20want,better%20marketing%20than%20%27Functor%27.) or functor, and is a routine practice. The UVM's [sequence body](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.2/html/files/seq/uvm_sequence_base-svh.html#uvm_sequence_base) method is an example of this.

A simpler example is using an `interface class` to define the common API and ask that the user implement the function

```
interface class API #(type P1);
   pure virtual function int foo(P1 i);
endclass
class myAPI #(int P2) implements API#(.P1(int));
   function int foo(P1 i);
      return P2;
   endfunction
endclass
...
API#(int) fp; 
myAPI#(42) imp = new; 

fp = imp;
fp.foo(54);
```